# How to update cookbooks to the latest versions safely?

Tags: chef-infra

I'm currently using Chef to deploy an instance of Jenkins via the [Chef supermarket Jenkins cookbook](https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/jenkins). I've made quite a few modifications to the _master_war.rb recipe file.

A new version of the Jenkins cookbook is available. My question is; how do I go about updating to the latest version of the cookbook without overwriting / losing all the modifications I've made to my current version of the cookbook?

I've checked out Chef's documentation on [cookbook versions](https://docs.chef.io/cookbook_versions.html), as well as the [knife cookbook documentation](https://docs.chef.io/knife_cookbook.html), but it still isn't very clear to me the proper way to go about updating your cookbooks safely.

Thanks for any guidance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the best way to update safely is to  never modify a community cookbook directly and use a wrapper cookbook.

This wrapper will `depends` on the community cookbook on a specific version in its metadata.rb (more details about this [here](https://docs.chef.io/config_rb_metadata.html#settings)):

```
depends "jenkins", "~> 2.3"
```

You will tweak attributes for the community cookbook in the wrapper cookbook attributes files.
They will be loaded after the community cookbooks ones (see [attributes precedence](https://docs.chef.io/attributes.html#attribute-precedence) for details), you have to keep a special attention on derived attributes (see https://coderanger.net/chef-tips/#5 for a workaround if you're so inclined), if a community cookbook has:

```
default['jenkins']['version'] = "2.0.1"
default['jenkins']['download_url'] = "https://some.site/artifacts/jenkins-#{node['jenkins']['version']}"
```

and you wish to just override the version, then you have to redo both attributes in the wrapper cookbook, the `download_url` on the second line won't be evaluated again.

It will then include the community cookbook in its recipe and take advantage of the `edit_resource` [recipe DSL method](https://docs.chef.io/dsl_recipe.html#) to modify the community cookbook behavior:

```
include_recipe 'jenkins::default'

edit_resource(:template, '/etc/jenkins/config.cnf') do
  source 'aliases.erb'
  cookbook 'aliases'
end
```

Comment: Thank you for a thorough reply. Aside from creating a wrapper cookbook and modifying the attributes for the community cookbook in the wrapper cookbook's attribute files, are there any other notable methods for updating cookbooks? For instance, moving all recipe code that differs from the original cookbook to its' own recipe file so as they cannot be overwritten by pulling down the most recent version of the cookbook?

Comment: That's possible only if you act on files /services (resources at large) not already handled by the community cookbook, redefining a template for the same file will end up breaking idempotency or unexpected results usually (hence the edit_resource method presented above). Of course the wrapper can add other resources without problem (that's kind of usual to add extra configuration included by main configuration)

Comment: Main idea is that you can then update your wrapper cookbook, increasing community version depends line and test it, once OK you propagate the wrapper via environment constraint or policy file (I should have included this in the answer)

Comment: do you find yourself updating to the most recent version of public Supermarket cookbooks very often? I'm trying to discern whether taking the time to create a new cookbook wrapper is worth the time and effort when compared with the gains.

Comment: @J0991 For my case it depends on which cookbooks, I always end up having to tweak at least the attributes to fit my needs, this (wrapper) allow me to update a cluster without touching the other clusters when needed. I present here what is the generally agreed best practice from Chef community, that's not the only option but its the one which has proven being the less likely to shoot yourself in the foot.

Comment: Great thank you very much for all the information. I've begun creating my own wrapper cookbook for the Chef Supermarket Jenkins cookbook as recommended. Prepare for more stackoverflow questions! :D